# How to uninstall android lost app

Tags: applications

I have installed android lost app from www.androidlost.com in my Samsung Tab 2 GT-P3100. How can I uninstall it?The app is not visible in the list of apps.

Comment: From the apps playstore page: *If you have trouble uninstalling, please read the [FAQ](http://www.androidlost.com/#faq) - there are several one-click solutions!* Have you checked that?

Answer (score 1):

To control the breadth of activities this app declares for itself, it probably has set itself up as a Device Administrator, to control the ability to run many aspects of your device automatically. It probably hides itself from uninstall while Device Administrator rights are active. I would start by searching Settings>Security>Device Administrators, and deselect the Android Lost App. Once deselected here, check the Task List to see if it has stopped running. Force Close if necessary. It may then appear on the Settings>Application manager list to allow for uninstall. If not, attempt a reboot, and check the Task List again. If necessary, Force Close the app again and attempt an uninstall. Understanding of these types of apps and their unmittigated control is why downloading from Unknown Sources is intentionally complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to their web site, choose "push from google play" and then when I used the menu button on my Samsung I could access a menu that allowed me to revoke administrative privileges and then remove the program.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 3 stripes appearing on the left corner of the screen. Click it. You will get next screen with few option in which 'Remove Administrative Rights'. Click it once to disable to the administrative rights. Now, you can delete the app like deleting any other app. Cheers!

Comment: OP said the app wasn't visible in the apps list! Should disabling the administrative rights make it visible?